# How do I show that $2\int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)f'(x)dx } =[f(b)]^{ 2 }-[f(a)]^{ 2 }$ using integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, show that

$$2\int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)f'(x)dx } =[f(b)]^{ 2 }-[f(a)]^{ 2 }$$

I know that I can easily solve this using $u$ substitution. I already did this. $u=f(x)$, $du=f'(x)dx$, and etc. I was able to show that the original equation is true with substitution.

I am now trying to show that the equation is true using integration by parts, but I am hitting a road block.

Here is what I have thus far:

Let $u=f(x)$, $du=f'(x)$, $v=f(x)$, $dv=f'(x)$

So, we can now say:

$$2\int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)f'(x)dx }=[2(f(x))^2]_a^b-2\int _{ a }^{ b }{ f'(x)f(x)dx }$$

I am unsure of how to proceed at this point. How can I get rid of that right hand side integrand?

Comment: Take the right hand side integrand to the left and don't forget to change the sign to  +. Then you are done!

Comment: Multiplication over real numbers is commutative (in case that was your worry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've actually done everything, you just don't realize it. The integrals on the left and right are the same.

So you have $4I = 2(f(b)^2 - f(a)^2)$ where $$I=\int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)f'(x)dx }$$ Just divide by $2$ and you're done!